# bringchildtofront of linearlayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontallist

In my application, I have linear layout with horizontal list view as child view. On clicking a horizontal list view I want to move that particular list view to top of linear layout. I have added the line in horizontal list view on click listener for moving top position.

> Blockquote linearlayout . bringchildtofront (horizontallistview);

The problem is horizontal list view is not moved to top position. Am i missing something,please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue:**

`bringToFront` method is used when you want to change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on top of other **sibling views** only.means you can use it to make some view on the front from the overlapped views.

**Solution:**

you need to use `addView(View child, int index)` and `removeViewAt(int index)`

**Reference:**

Have a look at [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#bringChildToFront%28android.view.View%29)